# ExceptionInInitializerError on DriverManager with MS SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, securityexception

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL Server DB using JDBC and on this line:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:" + url + ";user=dummy;password=dummy;";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

I'm getting this massive wall-of-text of an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(JceSecurityManager.java:65)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2543)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Cipher.java:2567)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:548)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:194)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:350)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:308)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:549)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1606)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at BusinessManager.Session.<init>(Session.java:33)
    at BusinessManager.BusinessManager.getSession(BusinessManager.java:172)
    at example.Example.ConfigureEnvironment(Example.java:198)
    at example.Example.main(Example.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:89)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot locate policy or framework files!
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:254)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:48)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:81)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:78)
    ... 22 more
```

I've followed a couple of links, made sure both server and client are using the same JDK (1.8.0_20).
I've also downloaded the "JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" and placed them in the JDK. I've also followed this [link](https://mxforum.mendix.com/questions/4382/) but I'm not sure whether I should be meddling with the JDK's "java.policy" files...

Comment: can you show the value of `url`?

Comment: the `url` is `localhost`

Comment: so `connectionUrl` is `"jdbc:localhost;user=dummy;password=dummy;"`? That can't be correct.

Comment: Correct syntax:     String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
         "databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=UserName;password=*****";

Comment: from where did you downloaded the JCE files? Are they for java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess based on the error is that you are attempting to connect to SQL with an SSL encrypted session but are using a self-signed certificate on the SQL Server. Per [Connecting with SSL Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879949%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> When the encrypt property is set to true and the
>   trustServerCertificate property is set to true, the Microsoft JDBC
>   Driver for SQL Server will not validate the SQL Server SSL
>   certificate. This is usually required for allowing connections in test
>   environments, such as where the SQL Server instance has only a self
>   signed certificate.

Try using:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:" + url + ";user=dummy;password=dummy;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;";
```

Also, your `url` variable contents should start with `sqlserver://`.